# C for loop not repeating

Tags: c, loops

I have a for loop that resizes and appends a number to an dynamically sized array. However the array only repeats a couple times then the program ends.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
int *primes = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < 15000; i++) {
    primes[i] = i;
    primes = (int*)realloc(primes, (i+2)*sizeof(int));
}

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(primes)/sizeof(int); i++) {
    printf("%i, ", primes[i]);
}

free(primes);
return 0;
}
```

This prints `0, 1,` then exits
Why does it not continue to 15000?

Comment: Try to `printf` the `sizeof(primes)`. It's not what you assume it is.

Answer (score 1):

`primes` is a pointer, which has a size of 8 bytes on a 64-bit computer. An `int` has 4 bytes. 8/4=2, so it runs twice.

Comment: Maybe you should precise that the problem come from the size evaluation of prime, an int pointer, in line : `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(primes)/sizeof(int); i++) {`